# Google Cloud SQL instance always in Maintenance status & Binary logs issue

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've had some of Google Cloud SQL MySQL 2nd Gen 5.7 instances with failover replications. Recently I noticed that the one of the instance overloaded with the storage overloaded with binlogs and old binlogs not deleted for some reason.
I tried restart this instance but it wont start since 17 March.

Normal process with binlogs on other server:
[image: normal server]

Problem server. Binlogs not clearing and server wont start and always under maintenance in the gcloud console. 
[image: problem server]

Also I created one other server with same configuration and not binlogs never clearing. I have already 5326 binlogs here when on normal server I have 1273 binlogs and they are clearing each day.
[image: new server]

What I tried with the problem server:
1 - delete it from the Google Cloud Platform frontend. Response: The instance id is currently unavailable.
2 - restart it with the gcloud command. Response: ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.restart) HTTPError 409: The instance or operation is not in an appropriate state to handle the request. Same response on any other command which I sent with the gcloud.

Also I tried to solve problem with binlogs to configure with `expire_logs_days` option, but it seems this option not support by google cloud sql instance.

Answer (score 2):

After 3 days of digging I found a solution. Binlogs must cleared automatically when 7 days past. In 8 day it must clear binlogs. It still not deleted for me and still storage still climbing, but I trust it must clear shortly (today I guess)

As I told - SQL instance always in maintenance and can't be deleted from the gcloud console command or frontend. But this is interesting because I still can connect to the instance with the mysql command like `mysql -u root -p -h 123.123.123.123`. So, I just connected to the instance, deleted database which unused (or we can just use mysqldump to save current live database) and then I just deleted it. In the mysql logs (I'm using Stackdriver for this) I got a lot of messages like this: `2018-03-25T09:28:06.033206Z 25 [ERROR] Disk is full writing '/mysql/binlog/mysql-bin.034311' (Errcode: -255699248 - No space left on device). Waiting for someone to free space...`. Let's me be this "someone".

When I deleted database it restarted and then it up. Viola. And now we have live instance. Now we can delete it/restore database on it/change storage for it.

Comment: The [public docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/tips#bin-log-impact) specify that Google Cloud SQL will retain logs from the past  7 backups. If for some reason your instance is stuck on maintenance and nothing can be done in your end, you can reach out for support or create a [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui). When setting replication, which is semi-synchronous, slow slave could affect performance on the master, so you might consider having the same type of instance as the master.